# Como puedo limitar la rotacion de la camara con este comando en unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity

> La version de Unity es 2018.4.36f1, basicamente quiero como cualquier otro shooter fps, poder mover la camara respecto al mouse, todo funciona bien, pero el personaje da 360 y eso como que no xd
>
> > Tambien agradeceria que me dijeran algun codigo para podes hacer el mouse invisible... gracias!

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour

```
    {
    public float speedH;
    public float speedV;

    float yaw;
    float pitch;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Usa Clamp para limitar el pitch

```
    public float speedH;
public float speedV;

float yaw;
float pitch;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -20, 20);

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: Hizo falta una explicación de `clamp`.

Comment: Entiendo el uso de clamp está ya bien explicado en la documentación oficial de Unity.

Comment: La idea es explicarlo a quienes no lo conocen.